# How to create a C++ compatible function object in LUA?

Tags: c++, c++11, lua

I'm thinking about how to design my APIs, I plan to have a C++ application with a scripting layer in LUA .

For a couple of key points in my design I would like to give the ability to the user to create a function object that represents what he wants to do in LUA, than send this function object from LUA to C/C++ .

In pseudo code, in C++ I have a `class T`

```
class T {
...
int num1 = 0;
float num2 = 0.0f;
std::string str{"NONE"};
...
};
```

And I would like to manipulate an instance of `T` with a `function object` provided from LUA like so

```
void applyFunc(T t,F f){
f(t);
}
```

The problem is that I can't find nothing in LUA that creates a function object like a C++11 lambda or `std::function` or any other object that can be considered a function object.

Really my point is: how to **define** a C++ compatible function object in LUA ?

Comment: You may find the [LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge) library helpful in this situation.

Comment: @TimCooper could you provide a working example for this ? Because I got the impression that any popular LUA<->C++ solution really works from C++ to LUA and not viceversa.

Comment: @user2485710: Getting C++ to call a Lua function is beyond trivial. The hard part is when you want that Lua code to be able to manipulate a C++ object, as in your example. That's the problem the libraries help with.

Comment: SWIG (www.swig.org) is a code generator that makes it really easy to wrap your C++ classes so they can be used from Lua. You then instantiate a Lua interpreter in your C++ app, execute code in the interpreter to load your Lua module (created via SWIG), and you can then run Lua scripts that use your C++ classes. I have a library lua-icxx which does the basics of this (work in progress so YMMV -- the part to integrate with SWIG is still only in SVN no release yet).

Comment: @Schollii I know SWIG and it's not what I want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944455/how-to-create-a-c-compatible-function-object-in-lua/21945211?noredirect=1#comment33259712_21945211

Comment: It's not clear if you need to know how to pass a function from Lua to C, or how to write the code to apply the function to a C++ class instance, or how to write the code to allow the function to read and write the instance fields, or how to wrap it all up in a callable object and fit it into your C++ design. Please indicate which of these you understand and which you don't.

Comment: @TomBlodget the path that I would like to walk is from LUA to C++ . The key node that prevents me from doing that is how to define, create, write a C++ function object in LUA, not a function, a function object, something like a lambda, an instance of `std::function` but that it's going to be created in LUA.

Comment: @user2485710: "write a C++ function object in LUA" You can't. Lua compiles to byte code and runs on a register-based virtual machine. C++ (typically) compiles to native machine code and runs on a hardware CPU. You can't create a native machine code function from Lua. However, you can easily achieve your desired *goal* -- "manipulate an instance of T with a function object provided from LUA", even using your preferred syntax (e.g. `applyFunc(f,t)`) -- if you listen to the responses you've been given.

Comment: @Mud I'm not discarding the given answers, they are simply not focused on my main point. It's strange that the C++ ABI are not considered a "valid protocol" from LUA. It would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @user2485710: **"they are simply not focused on my main point"** They are, 100%. You've been shown how to do exactly what you want to do. **"C++ ABI are not considered a 'valid protocol' from LUA"** Huh? How do you think Lua calls functions you provide it from C++? It's *written* in C. Of course Lua function themselves don't conform to it, they *aren't native code*, they are a sequence of [instructions](http://underpop.free.fr/l/lua/docs/a-no-frills-introduction-to-lua-5.1-vm-instructions.pdf) which get *processed by* native code (i.e. the Lua interpreter).

Comment: @Mud you are thinking about instructions and registers, I'm thinking about how function calls, methods and values are laid out in memory and how they are implemented. Anyway since there is no possibility I will accept that.

Comment: I'm thinking about all of the above: instructions, registers, the call stack, pointers, alignment, etc. -- all of that is used internally by *Lua interpreter*, and all of it is completely irrelevant and in fact off-limits to the *Lua language*. And none of it is even a little bit relevant to the answer to your problem. You *can* create methods in Lua that are passed an instance of a C++ class. In fact, that's a very common usage of Lua.

Comment: @Mud ok, but that's not what I need, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @user2485710: "that's not what I need". It's [what you asked for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944455/how-to-create-a-c-compatible-function-object-in-lua). Judging from the question, the answers you've been given are *probably* what you need. It just sounds like you know next to nothing about dynamic languages and need to get over that hump. If you want to create functions dynamically at runtime that can operate on a C++ object, you absolutely *can* do that in Lua. You're just not going to be creating native code at runtime to do that, not Lua, Ruby, Python, Perl, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I can't find nothing in LUA that creates a function object like a C++11 lambda or std::function or any other object that can be considered a function object.

[That's what the `function` keyword does.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9)
This *is* a lambda. It's easy enough to pass these to C++ and let the C++ code call them.

As for this:

> ```
> void applyFunc(T t,F f){  
>    f(t);  
> }
> ```

In principle it's easy: push the C++ object pointer onto the Lua stack as a `userdata` and call the Lua function. The problem is the Lua code can't do anything with a C++ pointer.

If you want the Lua code to be able to manipulate the object you pass it, you'll need to write manipulator methods in C++ and expose them to Lua. You usually do that by creating a metatable for the userdata.

[There are libraries that this that automatically for C++.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) If you want to do it by hand (my preference), you should probably start [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

If you Google "C++ object Lua __index" that should net you numerous examples. I could code up an example later, but I'm at work at the moment.

Comment: and how this fits in as an equivalent of a C++ function object and how to do what I asked for with this `function` keyword ? As far as I know that looks like more like a plain old `C` function.

Comment: @user2485710 Lua functions are simply one type of value. You can test a value to see if its type is "function". If so, you can call it with whatever parameters you want. Local and global variables, table members (values *and keys*), parameters and return values can all have functions as values. You want the user to create a function that takes one parameter `t` and allow them to invoke documented methods on it. Lua allows that, using "late binding", if you will. You just have to write the glue code on the C side of the `userdata` parameter `t`.

Comment: @TomBlodget the best I can do with that is using a `C` function or a function pointer, I need a function object, something like a C++11 lambda, please read the question. Your posts and comments are interesting but they are all OT.

Comment: Lua functions *are* lambdas, and they are closures, capable of carrying state. None of that is relevant to your question. You're not thinking through what `f(t`) actually *means*. Yes, you can pass `t` (a C++ object) to `f` (a Lua function), but *you have to provide a way for `f` to manipulate `t` from Lua* or it's completely worthless. It seems like your eyes glaze over when when you see what looks like binding a C++ object to Lua, but that's *exactly* what you need. Without it, you can't implement `applyFunc`.